# Mousing over different images makes different text appear in the same text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mouseevent

Thanks so much for your help. I am new to JavaScript and trying to learn, but it's a lot to take in. In the meantime, my team created a site where we have 5 different images that represent a capability. Under all those images, we want to have text appear. When you mouse over the image, the corresponding description of the capability should appear centered under all the images. If you move to a different image, the text should change, but it should be in the same location.

It would kind of be like jQuery tabs but with images.

If anyone could help with the code or point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Can we see some of the code, the HTML of the relevant area, and any attempts made?

Comment: It's just like a tab. Just put images in the DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use the `hover` method to add a [animation css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to your image text on hover. To update the text in your textbox just place the image text below the hovered image then you can find the text with jQuery and copy that text to the textbox with `.text(newText)`.

To find the text you first have to go to the parent of the image with `.parent()` (the `li` tag here) and then you can use `.find(class)` to go down to the image text.

For documentation to `.hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` see the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

A demo for what you're looking for see the demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/81Lx27wL/).

**To the css:**

The `overflow: hidden;` on the `li` tag is only to hide the text below the images. The li and the image have the same height so the text is invisble.

```js
var $textbox = $('#textbox'),
    handlerIn = function () {
        var $imgText = $(this).parent().find('.imgText'); // find the text
        $textbox.text($imgText.text()); // add the text to the p-tag
        $textbox.removeClass('animated fadeOut');
        $textbox.addClass('animated fadeIn');
    },
    handlerOut = function () {
        //var $imgText = $(this).parent().find('.imgText');
        $textbox.removeClass('andimated fadeIn');
        $textbox.addClass('animated fadeOut');
    };

$('img').hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imgText {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1" />
        <p class="imgText">first image text...</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2" />
        <p class="imgText">second image text...</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3" />
        <p class="imgText">third image text...</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<p id="textbox"></p>
```